# How to remove the false detection at border pixels of the output image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am a very much new to image processing. I have apply Gabor filter on a retinal image with 8 different orientations say 60,67.5,75,120,135,150,157.5,165 degree at different wavelengths.I have generated an output image. But I want to remove the false detection at border pixels of the output image. How do I do?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are asking without an example image. Try uploading one and posting a link.

Answer (score 1):

One option, if you have the Image Processing Toolbox is to use the [`imclearborder`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclearborder.html) function with a syntax like:

```
bw2 = imclearborder(bw);
```

Which gives as result:

```
bw                         bw2
```

[image: original and processed images]

Comment: Thanks a lot..... But I actually mean to say that I have a retinal image and after using Gabor filter I have generated a ground-truth image of that retinal image containing vessels. Along with that vessels, A false border pixel of the retinal is also generated which I have to remove.So please help me out from this.