# Extracting near-border elements of an image using logical operators and/or morphological transformations

Tags: image-processing

Using logical operators (intersection, difference...etc) and/or morphological transformations (erosion, dilation and skeletonization) and given an image as the one below (original image), how can all the elements which are cut by the image's frame be extracted ? in order to keep only whole ones.

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Oz3K.jpg)

Intended result:

[Near-border elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh6Xk.png)
 [Whole elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmGZn.png)

I have tried intersecting the original image with another representing only the frame, and then applying a dilation on the intersection (though it doesn't seem possible to me to reconstitute the elements by dilating lines) and here are the results: 
[An image representing only the frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLBtU.jpg)  [Intersection between the frame image and the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8z3p.jpg)  [Dilation of the intersection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXGhJ.jpg)

(The dilation was tired with circular and square structuring elements of sizes ranging from 3X3 to 51X51)

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is morphological reconstruction (flood-filling). Marker - border of image, mask - original image.
https://www.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/tag-team/Objects/m/64199_91822v00_eddins_final.pdf

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763924/how-to-remove-the-false-detection-at-border-pixels-of-the-output-image